# Failed to register bundle identifier, No profiles for 'com.demo.DemoApp' were found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

error 1:

> The app identifier cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

error 2:

> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.demo.DemoApp'.

Suddenly I am facing this error in Xcode. My bundle identifier is already unique. I am using the bundle identifier with Firebase and other places. I know changing the identifier removes the error but it is not a solution for me.

Is there any possibilites that if someone clones apps public repo from github and builds that project on his/her device may give me this trouble?

So what should I do now?

Comment: Go to xCode Settings -> Accounts -> Sign out, then Sign in again and click on Manual Download Profiles, then try again

Comment: @AhmedAlNeaimy I have tried it. But it does not fix the problem.